# How to upload file within Express API callback?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, file-upload, multer

I know how I can upload a file from a client to an Express server using `multer`.

However, this can only be done using a middle ware function.

What I am looking for is a way to upload files from within the callback of the Express API.

My use case is this:

1. Client uploads a CSV file having URLs of images.
2. I will download those images from given URLs
3. Then I will upload those images in MongoDb within Express API callback

( I am looking for how to do the 3rd step. )

Something like this:

```js
app.post('/uploadtoDB',multer.single('file'),(req,res)=>{

    let urls = parseCSV_and_GetUrls(req.file);
    urls.forEach((url)=>{
         downloadImage(url)
    });

    //Scan directory to get downloaded images 
    let stream = fs.createReadStream('/path/to/downloadedFile');

    //Upload the downloaded image to MongoDb
    uploadfile_to_MongoDB(stream); 
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would not recommend storing images directly in MongoDB. It is advisible to store them on a static filestore (S3) and just keep the url/reference to it in MongoDB.

If you really want to store it in MongoDB, you could convert the image to a base64-encoded string. Note that with this method you need to make sure that the resulting document is below 16 MB as this the [max. allowed doc size](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/limits/#BSON%20Document%20Size).

```
const fs = require('fs');

async function storeFileAsBase64EncodedString(pathToFile) {    
   const buffer = await fs.promises.readFile(pathToFile);    
   await db.collection('yourCollection').insertOne({ image: buffer.toString('base64') });    
}
```

Another option is to use GridFs, see [this](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/gridfs/#when-to-use-gridfs) for further details.